# How do I clear all items in a Chosen.js multiselect dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I want to REMOVE all items in the chosen.js multi select drop-down, How can I do this? I tried using..

```
var ddlSitesID = $("#SelectedSites option").length
if (ddlSitesID) {
    for (i = 0; i != ddlSitesID; i++) {
        $("#SelectedSites option").remove(i);
    }
}
```

But it does not work, please help.

Comment: if(...) $("#SelectedSites option").remove(); //try this

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work..

Comment: First of all, you try $("#SelectedSites") selector. Does it select your select or not ? If this selector selects your "select", $("#SelectedSites option").remove() must remove all options in your select.

Comment: The code I was using was right, it just needed to run $('#SelectedSites').trigger('chosen:updated'); after it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/j9yuL/131/](http://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/j9yuL/131/)

```
//To clear selection
$('#SelectedSites option').prop('selected', false).trigger('chosen:updated');

//Remove all items
$('#SelectedSites').html("");    
$("#SelectedSites").chosen().trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two way

-First way:

```
      $('#SelectedSites').html('');
```

-Second way:

```
      $('#SelectedSites').find('option').remove().end();
```

Comment: Can you post both html and js?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

First run this..

```
    var ddlSitesID = $("#SelectedSites option").length
    if (ddlSitesID) {
        for (i = 0; i != ddlSitesID; i++) {
            $("#SelectedSites option").remove(i);
        }
    }
```

then run this after it

```
$('#SelectedSites').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#SelectedSites").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
```